# How to thread lock 2 simple threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-lock

I am trying to demonstrate thread locking using a simple example, but unable to get it to work. My code uses locks and releases on two threads that simply print out a message. I have tried multiple variations, including removing the `time.sleep()` and passing the lock to the threads as an argument, but I'm obviously missing something fundamental about how locks work.

```
import threading
import time

thread_lock = threading.Lock()

ctr = 0

def thread_1():
    while True:
        global ctr
        thread_lock.acquire()
        ctr += 1
        print(ctr, 'thread_1 has added 1 to ctr')
        time.sleep(1)
        thread_lock.release()

def thread_2():
    while True:
        global ctr
        thread_lock.acquire()
        ctr += 1
        print(ctr, 'thread_2 has added 1 to ctr')
        time.sleep(1)
        thread_lock.release()

t_1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_1)
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_2)

t_1.start()
t_2.start()

# t_1.join()
# t_2.join()
```

Comment: I see you have posted some code. Have you tried it? Does it produce any output or any error messages?

Comment: Possibly you want to `time.sleep(1)` after releasing the lock ?

Comment: Try putting _something_ between the consecutive `.release()` `.acquire()` calls. A short sleep, or even a call to `print`, gives enough opportunity for the other thread to take control.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried the code and typically get some prints from thread_1 then some prints from thread_2 (no particular pattern), but never what i expect, i.e. Alternating prints from threads 1 and 2.

Comment: I have also tried moving time.sleep() to after the release. I have put it before to simulate the function doing something. I have also removed all time.sleep() and still get the same behaviour.

Comment: There is no reason to expect that thread 1 and 2 will alternate.

Comment: I guess i don't understand locking. I thought that thread_2 (assuming thread_1 acquired the lock first) will wait until thread_1 releases it. Then thread_2 will acquire the lock and thread_1 will wait until thread_2 releases it.

Comment: This *could* happen, but it is not guaranteed. Thread switching is governed by the GIL.  However, there *is* a way of making your thread 1 and 2 alternate. I shall post an answer . . .

Comment: Really appreciate the code, thanks. I will have read carefully and have a play around.

Comment: I think maybe i lost track of the purpose of threads while making the mre, i.e. I became obsessed with making the threads alternate rather than just letting them do their thing without interfering with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how using two locks usually results in the two threads alternating:

```py
import threading
import time

lock1 = threading.Lock()
lock2 = threading.Lock()

ctr = 0
run = True

def thread_1():
    global ctr
    print('thread_1')
    while run:
        lock1.acquire()
        time.sleep(0.001)
        lock2.acquire()
        ctr += 1
        print(ctr, 'thread_1 has added 1 to ctr')
        time.sleep(1)
        lock1.release()
        time.sleep(0.001)
        lock2.release()
        time.sleep(0.001)

def thread_2():
    global ctr
    print('thread_2')
    time.sleep(0.001)
    while run:
        lock1.acquire()
        time.sleep(0.001)
        lock2.acquire()
        ctr += 1
        print(ctr, 'thread_2 has added 1 to ctr')
        time.sleep(1)
        lock1.release()
        time.sleep(0.001)
        lock2.release()
        time.sleep(0.001)

t_1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_1)
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_2)

t_1.start()
t_2.start()

while ctr < 5:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
run = False
print('joining...')
t_1.join()
t_2.join()
```

Usual output:

```
thread_1
thread_2
1 thread_1 has added 1 to ctr
2 thread_2 has added 1 to ctr
3 thread_1 has added 1 to ctr
4 thread_2 has added 1 to ctr
5 thread_1 has added 1 to ctr
joining...
6 thread_2 has added 1 to ctr
```